# Django - Difference between sessions and Cookie?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

Hey every one i am trying to create user story for an website and face problem creating user story for session management and cookies management. can any one help me ?

Comment: Session data is stored at the *server* side, whereas cookies are stored at the client side.

Comment: May wanna add that the server-stored session is retrieved/identified using a client stored/sent cookie.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is that the one and only difference between sessions and cookies ? I also find that only difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases it is preferred to use sessions because the actual values are hidden from the client, and you control when the data expires and becomes invalid.
If it was all based on cookies, a user (or hacker) could manipulate their cookie data and then play requests to your site.

also if your storing big amount of data you should use sessions bc unlike cookies sessions can store an unlimited amount of data,
if your not, using cookies can also increase performance of ur site (going back and forth in different pages of your website)
for more information I think this website can help you [(Sessions vs Cookies)](https://www.javatpoint.com/session-vs-cookies)